# Is there a way to capture get or post variables using php?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want my php script to capture get or post variables. That is whether I have changed my method to get or post, the php script should be able to capture the variables in the same php variable . 
How do I achieve this?

**HTML Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("input[type=submit]").click(function(){
            //alert($(this).parents("form").serialize());
            $.ajax({  
                type: "get",
                url: 'file.php',
                data: $(this).parents("form").serialize(),  
                complete: function(data){  

                } ,
                success:function(data) { 
                    alert(data);
                }   
        });
        return false;
        })
    })
</script>
```

**file.php Code**

```
<?php

$name = $_POST["file"]?$_POST["file"]:$_GET["file"];
echo   $_POST["file"];
?>
```

The above code does not capture post variables .How do I capture post variables?

Comment: Why don't you print `$name` ?

Answer (score 7):

Use the [`$_REQUEST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) superglobal:

```
$name = $_REQUEST['file'];
```

Answer (score 2):

I've always used a function I wrote:

```
function getGP($varname) {
    if (isset($_POST[$varname])) {
        return $_POST[$varname];
    } else {
        return $_GET[$varname];
    }
}
```

Then just:

```
$name = getGP('file');
```

Comment: Well, although handy, this is not the smartest thing to do.

Comment: This function can be improved with a ternary operator, like
function getGP($var) {
     return isset($_POST[$var]) ? $_POST[$var] : $_GET[$var];
}

Answer (score 2):

if you would like to filter what is done via a `POST` or what is done via a `GET` use this:

```
//for the POST method:
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
   //here get the variables:
   $yourVar = $_POST['yourVar'];
}

//for the GET method:
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
   //here get the variables:
   $yourVar = $_GET['yourVar'];
}
```

otherwise use the _REQUEST:

```
$yourVar = $_REQUEST['yourVar'];
```

Answer (score 1):

`$_REQUEST` captures both `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 1):

Use `$_REQUEST`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Answer (score 1):

using $_REQUEST

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php